# Regex - the difference in \\n and \n

Tags: php, regex, datetime, syntax, scanf

Sorry to add another "Regex explanation" question to the internet but I must know the reason for this. I have ran this regex through RegexBuddy and Regex101.com with no help.

I came across the following regex (`"%4d%[^\\n]"`) while debugging a time parsing function. Every now and then I would receive an 'invalid date' error but only during the months of January and June. I mocked up some code to recreate exactly what was happening but I can't figure out why removing the one slash fixes it.

```
<?php
$format = '%Y/%b/%d';
$random_date_strings = array(
    '2015/Jan/03',
    '1985/Feb/13',
    '2001/Mar/25',
    '1948/Apr/02',
    '1948/May/19',
    '2020/Jun/22',
    '1867/Jul/09',
    '1901/Aug/11',
    '1945/Sep/21',
    '2000/Oct/31',
    '2009/Nov/24',
    '2015/Dec/02'
    );

$year = null;
$rest_of_string = null;

echo 'Bad Regex:';
echo '<br/><br/>';
foreach ($random_date_strings as $date_string) {
    sscanf($date_string, "%4d%[^\\n]", $year, $rest_of_string);
    print_data($date_string, $year, $rest_of_string);
}

echo 'Good Regex:';
echo '<br/><br/>';
foreach ($random_date_strings as $date_string) {
    sscanf($date_string, "%4d%[^\n]", $year, $rest_of_string);
    print_data($date_string, $year, $rest_of_string);
}

function print_data($d, $y, $r) {

    echo 'Date string: ' . $d;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Year: ' . $y;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Rest of string: ' . $r;
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Feel free to run this locally but the only two outputs I'm concerned about are the months of June and January. `"%4d%[^\\n]"` will truncate `$rest_of_string` to `/Ju` and `/Ja` while `"%4d%[^\n]"` displays the rest of the string as expected (`/Jan/03` & `/Jun/22`).

Here's my interpretation of the faulty regex:

- `%4d%` - Get four digits.
- `[^\\n]` - Look for those digits in between the beginning of the string and a new line.

Can anyone please correct my explanation and/or tell me why removing the slash gives me the result I expect?

I don't care for the HOW...I need the WHY.

Comment: That's `sscanf` syntax, it has nothing to do with regex :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I feel silly but less crazy now. I'll track down some sscanf format documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @LucasTrzesniewski pointed out, that's [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) syntax, it has nothing to do with Regex. The format is explained in the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) page.

In your pattern `"%4d%[^\\n]"`, the two `\\` translate to a single backslash character. So the correct interpretation of the "faulty" pattern is:

- `%4d` - Get four digits.
- `%[^\\n]` - Look for all characters that are not a backslash or the letter "n"

That's why it matches everything up until the "n" in "Jan" and "Jun".

The correct pattern is `"%4d%[^\n]"`, where the \n translates to a new line character, and it's interpretation is:

- `%4d` - Get four digits.
- `%[^\n]` - Look for all characters that are not a new line

Comment: Like @LucasTrzesniewski said above, is this syntax specific to sscanf? Or is this actually regex?

Comment: You're right, that's `sscanf()` syntax. I have updated my answer.